# Can sorbet handle private definitions of initialize() when called with new?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I am getting an error calling the initialize method:

```
# typed: true
class A
  extend T::Sig

  sig {params(x: Integer).void}
  private def initialize(x)
  end
end

def main
  A.new(91)  
end
```

Here is the result of sorbet:

```
editor.rb:11: Non-private call to private method initialize on A https://srb.help/7031
11 |  A.new(91)  
      ^^^^^^^^^
editor.rb:6: Defined in A here
 6 |  private def initialize(x)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Errors: 1
```

[https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%[…]0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Adef%20main%0A%20%20A.new(91)%20%20%0Aend](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%%5B%E2%80%A6%5D0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Adef%20main%0A%20%20A.new(91)%20%20%0Aend)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in Sorbet, since `initialize` is treated specially by the language and is thus *always* `private` by default anyway. In other words, your code is *100%* identical to the same code without `private`:

```ruby
# typed: true
class A
  extend T::Sig

  sig {params(x: Integer).void}
  def initialize(x)
  end
end

def main
  A.new(91)  
end

p A.private_instance_methods(false).include?(:initialize)
#=> true
```

[Which passes type checking with flying colors.](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(x%3A%20Integer).void%7D%0A%20%20def%20initialize(x)%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Adef%20main%0A%20%20A.new(91)%20%20%0Aend%0A%0Ap%20A.private_instance_methods(false).include%3F(%3Ainitialize)%0A%23%3D%3E%20true)

My *guess* is that Sorbet doesn't "know" about the special treatment of `initialize` in Ruby and thus treats it as a normal method. My second guess is that Sorbet contains a definition of [`Class#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) that looks like this:

```ruby
class Class
  def new(...)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(...)
    obj
  end
end
```

This means that as long as Sorbet *thinks* `initialize` is `public`, everything is honky-dory, but as soon as it *thinks* it is `private`, it fails.

However, the *actual* implementation of `Class#new` looks more like this:

```ruby
class Class
  def new(...)
    obj = allocate
    obj.__send__(:initialize, ...)
    obj
  end
end
```

If my assumptions are correct, there are two bugs in Sorbet that *normally* cancel each other out:

- The definition of `Class#new` is wrong. This *would* mean that you would always get an error because `initialize` is always `private`, except
- The default visibility for `initialize` is also wrong.

*However*, I have not checked those assumptions, so I could be completely off.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and opening an issue.